# Prove $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to L

Tags: real-analysis

$(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence and $L\in \mathbb R$. Suppose every subsequence has a (sub)subsequence that converges to L.

My work so far; I believe the right view is to use the definition of the (sub)subsequence of this $x_n$ and then somehow work up, by showing the subsequence is convergent and so $x_n$ is convergent. But when I work through it I cannot find how this works. Perhaps I need to think Cauchy? Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: If $x_n$ does not converge to $L$, construct a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that no subsequence of that can converge to $L$. Then you have a proof by contradiction. Look at the logical negation of the statement "$x_n$ converges to $L$", what does it give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for a contradiction that $x_n$ does not converge to $L$. Then there is an $\varepsilon >0$ such that for any $N$, there is some $n \geq N$ such that $|x_n - L| \geq \varepsilon$. This creates a subsequence $x_{N_n}$ of $x_n$ satisfying $|x_{N_n} - L| \geq \varepsilon$. Then there is a subsequence of it, say $x_{N_n^\prime}$,  which coverges to $L$. So there is some $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|x_{N_n^\prime} - L| < \varepsilon$. But of course this is impossible by construction of $x_{N_n}$.

Comment: With regards to $x_{N_n}$, the constructed sequence, I figure to be clear, we should take the extra step to order the generated set of little n's right? Because just saying this creates a subsequence $x_{N_n}$ is somewhat incorrect no? Because for each n in this naturally generated set, it's not true that the successive n is always larger than or equal to the previous one? I hope I come across at least somewhat clear.

Comment: @FlorianSuess That is true. Filling in those details for "This creates a subsequence $x_{N_n}$ of $x_n$..." would be good

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence does not converge to $L$ then there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $n$
There exists some $k>n$ such that $$|x_k-L|\ge \epsilon $$
That will generate a sequence  $x_k$ which does not have a subsequence converging to $L$